# How to add a tooltip to the dynamically created SVG element in angualrjs?

Tags: angularjs, svg, tooltip

We need the tooltip on the dynamically created circle. A svg circle is custom created in page and on hovering upon that tooltip should work.
Here is the snippet:

```
<td ng-if="fldc.selected && fldc.itemStatus != undefined">
  <span ng-if="fldc.itemStatus">
    <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="margin: 1px;">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="!fldc.itemStatus">
    <svg class="checkmark1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="margin: 1px;">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle1" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill1="none" />
    <path class="checkmark__check1" fill1="none" d="M16 16 36 36 M36 16 16 36" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Create a child title element

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [ngMouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover). You could apply it to the `span` containing the SVG. When you mouse over, you could show or hide a hover over. If you need examples of how to do it in CSS, you can look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mihaeltomic/pen/PqxVaq). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add 2 directives to your svg element `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` that map to methods in the controller and a tooltip container.  Then you pass the $event to the appropriate method, add some css properties and an active class.  Here is a working example:

```js
App = angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController);
  
function MainController($scope, $element){
  const ttElem = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('.tooltip'));
  $scope.showTooltip = function(event){
    ttElem.css('left', event.pageX + 'px');
    ttElem.css('top', event.pageY + 'px');
    ttElem.html('Content Here');
    ttElem.addClass('active');
  }
  
  $scope.removeTooltip = () => {
    ttElem.removeClass('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #21669e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #eee;
    display: none;
}

.tooltip.active {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <svg>
      <g class="toolfaces">
        <circle class="lg" ng-mousemove="showTooltip($event)" ng-mouseleave="removeTooltip($event)" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said. If you are happy with simple tooltips, just use `<title>` elements. These are the SVG equivalent of the `title="..."` attribute in HTML

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<td ng-if="fldc.selected && fldc.itemStatus != undefined">
  <span ng-if="fldc.itemStatus">
    <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="margin: 1px;">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="black"/>
    <path class="checkmark__check" stroke="limegreen" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
    <title>Yes!</title>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="!fldc.itemStatus">
    <svg class="checkmark1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="margin: 1px;">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle1" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="black" />
    <path class="checkmark__check1" stroke="limegreen" d="M16 16 36 36 M36 16 16 36" />
    <title>No!</title>
    </svg>
  </span>
</td>
```